# JQuery ¿Cómo seleccionar el valor de un select desde un array?

Tags: php, jquery, select

A ver si podéis ayudarme con esto.
Está en PHP conectado a una base de datos MySQL. Tengo un array que despliego en un select y aquí sin problema:

```
            echo "<div class='oferta_div'>";
            if($juguete['color'] != ''){ // si la base de datos tiene colores guardados
            $array_color = explode(',',$juguete['color']); //separa el string de colores en elementos del array
                echo "<div class = 'color'>
                        <span>Elige color</span>
                            <select class='select_juguete' name='color' id='color'>";
                                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array_color);$i++){
                                    echo "<option>".$array_color[$i]."</option>";
                                }
                          
                           echo"</select>
                       </div>";
        }
```

Ahora quiero que la opción elegida aparezca en un input='text' usando JQuery:

```
 <script>
     var color = $('#color').val();
         
     $('#color').change(function(){
        $('#color_input').val(color);
     })
 </script>
```

El problema es que cuando elijo una opción, el input='text' muestra siempre el primer valor del array y no lo cambia nunca, ni aunque seleccione otros valores después.
¿Me ayudáis por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El script sería de la siguiente manera:

```
<script
    $('#color').change(function(){
        var color = $(this).val();
        $('#color_input').val(color);
    })
</script>
```

Es importante recordar que el `$(this)` lee la instancia padre que en este caso es `$('#color')`

Comment: ¡Me lo has arreglado @KevinDelva! Muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada compañero ;)